# Get a pie chart of latest custom variable (software version) from each user using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, statistics

I'm trying to use custom variables to track client side software version number. It working great so far: the value of the user scoped custom variable is being sent to GA and I'm able to see the result on my dashboard.

The only problem is that I can't find how to get only the last value submitted by a user and have a pie chart diagram showing the proportions of users running each version.

Is this even possible?

BTW I'm still using ga.js through Pyga Python module so using Dimensions is out of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, if using a visitor (user) scoped custom variable for the software version number then it should report the last value set for a visitor which is the one applied to the current and future sessions... until that gets overwritten by a another/newer value.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

Where are you trying to create the pie chart? You may want to look into Data Studio 
https://support.google.com/datastudio/?hl=en#topic=6267740
or possibly the Embed API
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/

Comment: Thanks for the datastudio suggestion. I didn't knew this tool. Looks promising! :-)